# Missing quotes around keys in AFJSONRequestOperation result?

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, afnetworking

Been stuck all day with this and reach out to get some help solving this asap. Any help would be great. Thank's :-)

**The missing quotes**

Got this AFJSONRequestOperation request from the web and it works great exept for one crucial fault: some keys are missing the quotes around there values = cant use them! There's obviusly some parsing going on in the AFNetworking background since the values come back i alphabetical order + "trimmed" of some of the qoutes on some values. But I just want the webdata "as is"...

**The format should look like this;**
theKey = "theValue";

**But sometimes it looks like this;**
theKey = theValue;     // Note the missing quotes around the value

**The web output json:**

I've also checked that my json is correct formatted coming from the server, the output looks like this;

```
{"results":[{"ID":"3","Row_state":"Visible","CustName":"Customer Name","CustReferens":"Customer Referens","CustReferensMobil":"123456mob","CustNotes":"Customer Notes","Tel":"123456tel","Fax":"123456fax","Web":"www.example.se","Mail":"info@example.se","Street":"The road 5","Zip":"11122","City":"Stockholm","Products":"","Images":"","Logo":"myLogo.jpg","Text":"A lot of text goese here...","Seller":"","Favorite":"YES"},
```

**In the app I get this result;**

```
results =     (
            {
        City = Stockholm;          // Note the missing quotes around the value
        CustName = "Customer Name";
        CustNotes = "Customer Notes";
        CustReferens = "Customer Referens";
        CustReferensMobil = 123456mob;     // Note the missing quotes around the value
        Favorite = YES;             // Note the missing quotes around the value
        Fax = 123456fax;          // Note the missing quotes around the value
        ID = 3;             // Note the missing quotes around the value
        Images = "";
        Logo = "myLogo.jpg";
        Mail = "info@example.se";
        Products = "";
        "Row_state" = Visible;      // Now key got quotes + Note the missing quotes around the value
        Seller = "";
        Street = "The road 5";
        Tel = 123456tel;         // Note the missing quotes around the value
        Text = "A lot of text goese here...";
        Web = "www.example.se";
        Zip = 11122;       // Note the missing quotes around the value
    },
```

**Instead of this expected result** (all keys with quotes around the value);

```
results =     (
            {
        City = "Stockholm";
        CustName = "Customer Name";
        CustNotes = "Customer Notes";
        CustReferens = "Customer Referens";
        CustReferensMobil = "123456mob";
        Favorite = "YES";
        Fax = "123456fax";
        ID = "3";
        Images = "";
        Logo = "myLogo.jpg";
        Mail = "info@example.se";
        Products = "";
        "Row_state" = Visible;
        Seller = "";
        Street = "The road 5";
        Tel = "123456tel";
        Text = "A lot of text goese here...";
        Web = "www.example.se";
        Zip = "11122";
    },
```

**My code for this;**

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.se/api.lasso"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, id jsonObject) {
                                            NSLog(@"JSON Responce ÅF: %@",jsonObject);
                                            // Add result (an array from JSON) to NSMutableArray
                                            _restFeed = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"];
                                            NSLog(@"RestA-OListTVC > ViewDidload > AFN ÅF: _restFeed count = %i",[_restFeed count]);
                                            // Reload table with new data
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                            }
failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
            NSLog(@"Recieved an HTTP %d", responce.statusCode);
            NSLog(@"The error was: %@",error);
            }];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All JSON keys have quotes around them--that's part of the specification. However, when turned into an NSDictionary, their keys lose the quotes and just become `NSString` objects.

JSON `{"a": 1}` => Objective-C `@{@"a" : @(1)}`

`NSLog` will strip the quotes around strings that don't contain whitespace. Don't use the output of `NSLog` as the literal representation of what you're getting back. Just use the values as expected, with `valueForKeyPath:` and it should all work just fine.

Comment: Thank's Matt. That fixed the problem :-) 
_Tip: Maybe you should post something about this on the AFN Wiki, just in case others need it?_